TLS CA certificate error installing ipyleaflet module in Jupyter notebook
When I tried to install ipyleaflet in Jupyter notebook using code: pip install ipyleaflet the below error is encountered.

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
how to solve this

I am expecting to download ipyleaflet in Windows.

Please edit the post to include actions that you have attempted so far, and if they led to any change. Check out similar questions as [1] or [2].
